# How do i replace all elements of a vector with a scalar

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector (or array)

`A = [2 3 4]`

I want to replace all elements of each row with a scalar value of 4. I have the code:

`for ii = 1: size(A, 1)
    A(ii,:) = 4
end`

This returns `A = [4 4 4]`. How can i obtain a `1x1` matrix: `A = [4]` rather than the `1x3` matrix?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just create a new variable that is scalar?

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. Please see my comments below concerning this.

Comment: I don't understand why Aaron's suggestion won't work. Just assign a scalar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your comments. Although it says i should assign a scalar, it didn't say how i could do that effectively. Here is what works:

```
A = [2 3 4; 1 3 2];

for ii = 1: size(A, 1)
   B(ii,:) = A(ii,3)  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the NxM vector/matrix/array with a scalar variable by just assigning it a scalar.

Example:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
A =
    [1 2 3]
>>> A = 4
A =
    4
```

If I remember right, a scalar in MATLAB is a 1x1 matrix

Comment: Thanks @sharifi. This won't work because i'll need the result to make further computations within the loop in which case the value of 'A' might possibly change after each iteration. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @User1772 Yeah I think I understand. Is it safe to assume that the value you're replacing `A` with is the last value in the 1x3 matrix `A` ?

Comment: yes it is safe. This is because there will be couple of 'IF' statements that will replace A by assigning the 1st, 2nd, or last elements. Thanks!

Comment: In that case try 
`B = A(index); A = []; A=B;`

Answer (score -1):

```
for i = 1:10
    eval(['x_' num2str(i) ' = i^2']);
end
```

This solution has 2 issues:

1. Create scalar is slower than assign value to a matrix.
2. Challeng to reference to the new scalars later.

Source

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/29712-creating-a-new-variable-in-each-iteration

Comment: `eval` is a crappy solution. -1.  Please read this informative post by Loren Shure from MathWorks as to why `eval` should be avoided and alternative techniques to accomplish what `eval` does: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/

Comment: The link does not work. However, I mentioned the disadvantage fo this method.

Comment: Those disadvantages have nothing to do with why `eval` sucks.  BTW, the link does work. MathWorks probably had a temporary problem.

Comment: @rayryeng do you think should I remove this answer or write its side-effect only.