# How do i replace all elements of a vector with a single value?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Permit me to use the following example from:
[How do i replace all elements of a vector with a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42213966/how-do-i-replace-all-elements-of-a-vector-with-a-scalar/42214194?noredirect=1#comment71665220_42214194)

which says:

I have a vector (or array)

`A = [2 3 4; 1 3 2]`

I want to replace all elements of each row with the last element. The code below works as suggested by the OP.

```
for ii = 1: size(A, 1)
  B(ii,:) = A(ii,3)  
end
```

This returns: `B = [4; 2]`. In my case however, I want to retrieve the result such that the original variable A (rather than B) is returned as `A = [4; 2]`. I tried to copy **B** back to **A** but it gives me my original array `A` rather than the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to assign `B` to `A` after the loop

```
for ii = 1:size(A, 1)
    B(ii, :) = A(ii, end);
end

A = B;
```

Or you could remove the loop all-together and just grab the last column of `A`

```
A = A(:, end);
```

If you want to replace, *all* elements of each row of `A` with the value in the last column of each row you could instead do:

```
A = A(:, repmat(end, [1, size(A, 2)]));
```

Comment: Thank you @Suever. The problem with this is that i need `A` for further computations within the loop. There are series of IF statements that decide whether the 1st, 2nd or 3rd elements should be replaced and then the result is further utilized within the loop. Is there no way `B` can be copied to `A` within the loop?

Comment: @oma11 you can't eat the cake and have it too, either you want to retain `A` or you want to change it. The second example in this answer should be just what you look for. Simply, instead of assigning it back to `A`, put the expression `A(:, end)` directly where you need this values.

Comment: @EBH that's an awesome observation.  The 2nd code works perfectly. Thank you so much. Thank you **Suever** for your help.

Comment: Oops! i just realized this gives the expected result, but then this result isn't stored, hence i can't make use of it in the subsequent lines of code. Any further suggestions on this please?

Comment: @oma11 As EBH stated it *can't* maintain the old version since you're overwriting `A`. If you don't want to overwrite `A` you could either do `Aold = A; A(:, end);` or `B = A(:,end)`

Comment: Thanks @Suever. I have found another way around this. I tried to avoid using the variables `'A'` and `'B'` any further.